# Cambiar el nombre en mi url de la controladora MVC4

Tags: c#, mvc

Necesito cambiar mi Url:
localhost:44301/service por localhost:44301/product

service es la controladora, solo quiero cambiar su nombre por product pero seguir llamando a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos maneras sencillas de lograrlo:

1. Cambiando el nombre del controlador: dado que el framework utiliza el nombre del controlador para mapear la acción, puedes cambiar el nombre de controlador de "Service" a "Productos". Ejemplo:

   ```
   public IActionResult Productos()
   {
       ... //Método
   }
   ```

De esta manera, tu URL sería como "localhost:44301/Productos".

2. Otra manera de lograrlo es con *ruta por atributo*: de esta manera no es necesario cambiar el nombre del método, sino, simplemente indicarle al framework cuál es la ruta para alcanzar ése método. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   [Route("nombreDelDominio/Productos")]
   public IActionResult Services()
   {
       ... //Método
   }
   ```

Para más información sobre Attribute Routing, puede consultar el siguiente [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: Me sirvio tu segunda opcion. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias realizar un redirect al otro controller, algo como ser

```
public class ServiceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product");
    }
}
```

de esta forma cuando invocas a service pasaras al controller de product

Si necesitas trabajar con el routing en MVC 4 vas a tener que aplicar algo como lo siguiente

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "service",                                           
            "service/{action}",                            
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" }  
        );
```

[Creating Custom Routes (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

Comment: En realidad necesito que service pase a llamarse product. product no es una controladora, solo es un nombre para service. Espero que me entiendas. He visto que se podria hacer con UrlRewriter

Comment: en ese caso podrias definir el atributo [RoutePrefix("products")] en la clase del controller service https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-mvc-5-attribute-routing

Comment: Gracias, voy a implementarlo.

Comment: Yo estoy usando MVC4 el enrutamiento de atributos Mapmvcattributeroutes() no se puede implementar.

Comment: edite la pregunta agregando info como podrias definir el routing, lee la doc para antender sobre el tema

Comment: igual sino me equivoco en este caso no estarias cambiando la url, sino que estarias redireccionando como resuelve el controller donde ingresa cuando escribes esa url, o sea aunque escribes service o product ambos resuelvesn al controller de product, pero no te cambia la url, como si lo haria un redirect